# ngrx entity upsertOne by selectId

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I have the following action

`export const updateSuccess = createAction('Success', props<{ someId: string }>());`

And I have an adapter in the reducer like this

```
export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Model> = createEntityAdapter<Model>({
  selectId: (item: Model) => item.someId,
  sortComparer: false
});
```

Now when I update an item, the backend is sending that `someId`. So I do not have the full Model data at that point. So I was thinking I need to filter the entities I have in the state and `upsertOne` with that filtered item.

So something like this

```
on(actions.updateSuccess, (state, payload) =>
 adapter.upsertOne(state.entities.filter(entitiy => entity.someId === payload.someId), { ...state, someOtherProperties: 'values' })
),
```

But this looks incorrect and gives errors. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `upsertOne`

> updateOne: Update one entity in the collection. Supports partial updates.

https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter#adapter-collection-methods

```
on(actions.updateSuccess, (state, payload) =>
 adapter.upsertOne({ id: 1, foo: 'bar' }, state)
),
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I am not sure you actually read my question. I did mention that I want to use upsertOne, but for upsertOne the first argument should be the Model, while I only have `someId`.

Comment: It should not be the whole model, it just needs the id and the properties you want to update

Comment: But is there a way to get an item by id in the reducer?

Comment: `state.entities.filter(entitiy => entity.someId === payload.someId)`

Comment: state.entities.find(entitiy => entity.someId === payload.someId)